# CefSharp documentcompleted

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to use cefshar browser in C# winforms and need to know how I know when  page completely loaded and how I can get browser document and get html elements,

I just Initialize the browser and don't know what I should do next:

```
  public Form1()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com");
            BrowserContainer.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
```

Comment: Read the general usage guide, Google CefSharp general usage. It's on the wiki

Answer (score 17):

CefSharp has a [LoadingStateChanged](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_LoadingStateChanged.htm) event with `LoadingStateChangedArgs`.

[LoadingStateChangedArgs](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/LoadingStateChangedEventArgs.cs) has a property called `IsLoading` which indicates if the page is still loading.

You should be able to subscribe to it like this:

```
browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
```

The method would look like this:

```
private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsLoading)
    {
        // Page has finished loading, do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

I believe you can get the page source like this:

```
string HTML = await browser.GetSourceAsync();
```

You'd probably need to get to grips with something like [HtmlAgility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to parse it, I'm not going to cover that as it's off topic.

Comment: Thanks this really helpful

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using:

```
using CefSharp;

wbAuthorization.AddressChanged += OnAddressChanged;
```

and

```
private void OnAddressChanged(
    object s,
    AddressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Address.StartsWith(EndUri))
    {
        ResultUri = new Uri(e.Address);
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

`EndUri` is the final page I want to examine and `ResultUri` contains a string I want to extract later. Just some example code from a larger class.